# How To Insert Form Data In 2 different tables using single form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Here's the form where the user inputs the data in it.

```
<form action="addemployee.php" method="POST" id="addEmployeeToDataBase">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="UserName..." class="txtInput" required="" />
  <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name..." class="txtInput" required="" />
   <br />
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address..." class="txtInput" required="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..." class="txtInput" required="" />
   <br />
  <select name="dept" id="txtInput">
      <option value="-1">Select Department</option>
      <option value="Back-Office">Back-Office</option>
      <option value="HR">HR</option>
      <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
      <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
      <option value="Technical">Technical</option>
  </select>
     <br />
  <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address..." class="txtInput" required=""/>
  <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City..." class="txtInput" required="" />
     <br />
  <input type="text" name="pincode" placeholder="Pin/Postal/Zip Code..." class="txtInput" required="" />
  <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country..." class="txtInput" required="" />
     <br />
  <p style="font-size: 17px;" />Date of Joining:<input type="date" name="joiningdate" placeholder="Joining Date" class="txtInput" required="" />
     <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Employee"/>
```

Now I want to use the sql statement where the inputted data will send to the different tables simultaneously.

```
Table employee (emp_id, username, email, password, dept, address, city, pincode, country and joiningdate).

Table dept (dept_id, dept_name, dept_head, and emp_id).
```

This form basically inserts into the employee table.

Now the "question" is that I want to insert the data with single form into employee and dept  tables respectively, where the input data of dept from the form should also insert into dept_name column of the dept table and should also update the emp_id of the dept table with the inputted data.

Please guide me through this.

Comment: Is your emp_id auto incremented?

Comment: Yep, it is auto_incremented

Comment: Ok then related answer already given by others

Answer (score 2):

```
$query1= "INSERT INTO employee ( username, email,...)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."', ...)";
        if($result1 = mysql_query($query1))
        {
            $emp_id = mysql_insert_id();

            $query2= "INSERT INTO dept ( emp_id, dept_name, ...)
            VALUES ('".$emp_id."', '".$_POST["dept_name"]."',...)";

            if($result2 = mysql_query($query2))
            {
                //success msg
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First insert data into employee table after that using mysql function `last_insert_id` you can get emp_id value and inter into department table.

Assuming, emp_id is auto incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

This might help (I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and LAMP it is working for me)

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO users_account_details (uname,email,pass1,pass2) 
VALUES('$_POST[uname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[pass1]',DES_ENCRYPT('$_POST[pass2]'))";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO users_personal_details (name,gender,dob,address,mobile) 
VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[gender]','$dob','$_POST[address]','$_POST[mobile]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
```